# One Strange NetWorkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, xmpp, smack

As far as we know, we can't execute a web connection in the UI thread, and try to do it on the Thread or AsyncTask, and I choose to run the web connection in the runnable Thread. When i click the button, log show me the code right with `connection.connect();` happened to be a NetworkOnMainThreadException, but you know, from my code below, I already wrote my networkconnecton code in the thread, so, anybody show me the right way to deal with this problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btn_send;
    private EditText et_content;


    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_sendms);

        et_content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_inputcontent);

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(onClicListener);

    }

    public OnClickListener onClicListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            handler.post(task);
        }

    };

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Runnable task = new Runnable() {



        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

         ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    "192.168.1.108", Integer.parseInt("5222"), "dell-PC");

            AccountManager accountManager;

            connectionConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
            connectionConfig.setSendPresence(true);

            connection = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfig);

            try {

                connection.connect();
                accountManager = connection.getAccountManager(); // 
                connection.login("admin", "888889");
                ChatManager chatManager = connection.getChatManager();

                Chat newChat = chatManager.createChat("bryanwu@qq.com",
                        new MessageListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void processMessage(Chat chat,
                                    Message message) {

                            }
                        });

                try {
                    newChat.sendMessage(et_content.getText().toString());
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                et_content.setText("");

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // 

        }

    };

}
```

Comment: Don't use a `Handler`.  It runs on the same thread that it is bound to, in the case the UI main thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a handler on the ui thread. You run your network related operation in the runnable run method. So you are running network related operation on the ui thread.

Use a `Thread` or `Asynctask`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Quoting from the doscs

Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. **When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.**

If you run network related operation on the ui post honeycomb you will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html